# Mongo service stop working suddenly in Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

I've installed the MongoDb in a Ubuntu 18 GCP compute engine instance. Sometimes this mongo service got stop suddenly without any notice. Does anyone have any opinion to sort out this issue?

***`systemctl status mongod.service`* output**
[image]

**mongod.conf file output**
[image]

**Mongo log file output**
[image]

Comment: Review the system log files. Review the MongoDB log files. Verify the service status with **sudo systemctl status mongodb**. The problem could be as single as the service is not set to auto restart. Edit your question with details.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated the above question with mongod service status and mongo.conf file

Comment: But you left out the important parts, the log files that show a problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley Have a look, I've updated above question with the log file as well